# Create dynamic Component React (Native)

Tags: reactjs, react-native

i get from web sevice array of object `[{"id:1","title": "News",....},"id":2, "title": "History", .....}]`, so i want to create tab and scroll using react-native-scrollable-tab-view https://github.com/skv-headless/react-native-scrollable-tab-view, for static it work nice , but i don't know how to make dynamic because admin can add more title any time so static not work for this purpose.

In my code i do like this

```
 constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            ws: []
        };
    }
```

Also

```
componentDidMount() {
        fetch('http://localhost:8000/api/getThemeByOrganisations', {
            }).then((response) => response.json())
                .then((res) => {
                    this.setState({ 
                        ws : ws
                     });
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    console.error(error);
                });
    };
```

I want to make component name like that i get from web service (title) example `NewsComponent` 
In the end i want to do like this but dynamic

```
var App = React.createClass({
  render() {
    return (
      <ScrollableTabView renderTabBar={() => <CustomTabBar someProp={'here'} />}>
        <ReactPage tabLabel="React" />
        <FlowPage tabLabel="Flow" />
        <JestPage tabLabel="Jest" />
      </ScrollableTabView>
    );
  }
});
```

So here i want to do like for in "ws" and create dynamic Page , So anyone can help me and thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To render components from an array of objects, you can use `map`. An example would be:

```
render() {
  return (
    <View>
      {myArray.map(item => <TargetComponent {...item}/>)}
    </View>
  )
}
```

Comment: Did your `TargetCoponent` have re-render when up array in state?

Comment: yes, when you do `{this.state.myArray.map(item => <TargetComponent {...item}/>)}` and the state changes, the entire list will re-render

Answer (score 0):

So for using react-native-scrollable-tab-view 
First i create new component `ResultItem`

```
 var ResultItem = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
        <Text tabLabel>
            {this.props.result.nom}
        </Text>  
    );
  }
});
```

Second in render Main Component

```
<ScrollableTabView
               renderTabBar={() => <ScrollableTabBar />}>
               {this.state.ws.map(function (result) {
                             return <ResultItem key={result.id} result={result} tabLabel={result.nom}/>;
                        })}
                    </ScrollableTabView>
```

It work nice for dynamic render

Comment: Did your `TargetCoponent` have re-render when up array in state?